# Outlook DASL Filter - Custom Search

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to write a DASL filter to combine three queries:

**Get all mail with no category and no flag.**

```
("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" IS NULL 
AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:messageflag" IS NULL)
```

**Get all mail that is categorized as "Ryan" and flagged with a red "Today" flag.**

Don't know how to write this one.

**Get all mail that is uncategorized and flagged with a red "Today" flag.**

Don't know how to write this one.

Once I have the individual queries, I will combine and OR them. I am stuck on how to filter the flag value.